# Does using fuzziness disable prefix search in a simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

When using [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) with the prefix operator `*` **and** a fuzziness value `~N` on the same word the prefix search appears seems to be disabled.

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Abcd*~2",
      "fields": ["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

It's very obvious that prefix gets disabled whenever you set the fuzziness to 0 and the query becomes `Abcd*~0` then there is no prefix search and no fuzziness.

This isn't mentioned in the docs so I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong.

I've tried:

- swapping the operator order: `Abcd~2*` -- in `_explain` this introduces fuzziness variations but omits the prefix operator
- using parens for precedence: `(Abcd*)~2` -- in `_explain` this uses the prefix but omits the fuzziness operator<sup>1</sup>
- duplicating the word: `(Abcd* Abcd~2)` -- this works, it obviously shows the reunion of both queries instead of the composition of both effects<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming that in this case `~2` shouldn't be interpreted as the SLOP operator because there is no phrase (no quotes).

<sup>2</sup> I can understand that compositing those effects may generate too many possible variants -- fuzzy adds 50 variants then prefix searches for each of those, that

Comment: In query string it is mentioned that 
"Avoid mixing fuzziness with wildcards
Mixing fuzzy and wildcard operators is not supported. When mixed, one of the operators is not applied" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#avoid-widlcards-fuzzy-searches. I think this will apply to simple_query_string too

Comment: It probably shares an underlying implementation. Thank you @jaspreetchahal
Can you please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per query-string [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#avoid-widlcards-fuzzy-searches)

> Mixing fuzzy and wildcard operators is not supported. When mixed, one
>   of the operators is not applied. For example, you can search for app~1
>   (fuzzy) or app* (wildcard), but searches for app*~1 do not apply the
>   fuzzy operator (~1).

It considers either wildcard or fuzzy whichever is first.
For Abcd~2* It is just returning all the documents